# In moderation tools (on SO), should 'Lowest voted answers' ever list answers with -1 votes?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, moderation

The moderation tools show the lowest voted answers, but is it sensible to show answers with just -1 votes?  I'd venture to suggest that it isn't generally helpful.  As of a couple of minutes ago (2010-01-01 20:37 -08:00), there was one answer with -1 vote listed.  I suspect there were more such answers, but only space for one in the list.  I'd venture to suggest that one downvote doesn't not usually warrant the listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a time component to that list (2 days being the default) so I'm pretty confident that the question listed with -1 votes is probably the most recent question with that score.  All of the lists on the moderation page look to be set up to display 15 links.  If there aren't enough answers voted lower than -1 to fill the list, it makes sense to me that it should be filled out with the most recent questions from selected time period with -1 votes.

Comment: Well, for lack of other contribution, I accept this answer.  I'm not entirely convinced that the -1 should ever show up as warranting moderation, but it most certainly isn't a major issue.

Comment: I definitely agree with the "warranting moderation" point.  I usually only look at the list to see if anything stands out.  I certainly don't have time to check out every -1 answer. :)